# Mirror / Duplicate Github Wiki to the repo

Tags: git, github

I want to have a wiki-only github repo. But I want to have the master branch of the repo actually be the wiki repo itself.

It seems I can clone the wiki like this:

https://github.com/reggi/wiki.wiki.git

And the repo with these urls:

- https://github.com/reggi/wiki.git
- git@github.com:reggi/wiki.git

Is there any way to have the repo automatically be updated with the wiki's contents? Either using mirroring or a hook somehow?

Comment: Maybe you want to investigate [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)?

Comment: @larsks thanks for your comment, but github pages has nothing to do with what I'm trying to do. I don't want to serve html of any.

Comment: Sure you are.  What's  wiki but a way to serve HTML?  GitHub pages let's you have your content in an actual GitHub repository, and provides facilities for automatic Markdown-to-HTML conversion just like the wiki does.  It requires a little more work to set up, but you get a lot more flexibility.

Comment: @larsks I want to use the wiki editor to compose pages. Is that clear? Your proposal completely ignores the whole wiki aspect of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use following format.

```
https://github.com/<repos_name>.wiki.git
```

So In your case:

```
https://github.com/reggi.wiki.git
```

Hope to help you.

Answer (score -2):

Did you ever find a way to do this?

I'm interested in doing exactly this, with the mirror being the gh-pages (Github Pages) branch of the repository

The only way I can see to do it is to have an intermediate remote repository (possibly cloned from wiki.wiki.git with --mirror or --bare) on a server able to respond to a commit webhook from the wiki by pulling from wiki.wiki.git and pushing to wiki.git

UPDATE:

An example of this (from gitlab to github, but in principle the same) in php is at

https://git.hazaarlabs.com/jamie/gitlab-sync

https://github.com/JAZ-013/gitlab-sync